# Jquery check if children contain text

Tags: jquery, contains, children

I am trying to build a small searchfilter based on a simple input-field.
The jquery method should fadeOut all the rows of my table which do not contain the "name" I am searching for.

I know that `:contains` checks for text within the selected element, but somehow this seems not to work for all children of the element.

Is there a way to solve this problem without using `.each()` loops through all the children?

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Q6sHG/

**HTML**

```
<input id="searchBar" type="text" class="form-control">

<table class="table table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Surname</th>
            <th>First name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
       <tr>
           <td>Doe</td>
           <td>John</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
           <td>Smith</td>
           <td>John</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
           <td>Johnson</td>
           <td>Ann</td>
       </tr>
       [...]
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**JQuery**

```
$('#searchBar').keyup(function(){
        var name = $(this).val();
        if(name === "") {
            $( 'tbody>tr' ).fadeIn();
        } else {
            console.log("Search for: "+name);
            $( 'tbody>tr:contains( name )' ).fadeIn();
            $( 'tbody>tr:not(:contains( name ))').fadeOut();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You aren't filtering on the variable. Try the following instead

```
$( 'tbody>tr:contains('+name+')' ).fadeIn();
$( 'tbody>tr:not(:contains('+name+'))').fadeOut();
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/dschu012/Q6sHG/1/)